# Azure Data Factory Lookup with JSON dataset considers JSON keys as case insensitive

Tags: json, azure, azure-data-factory

I am receiving JSON files in a azure blob container which I wanted to read and load into single column database table.

I have designed an ADF pipeline which makes use of "Lookup" activity with JSON dataset.

My json looks like below:

```
{
    "G_key1": "Value_1",
    "G_key2": "Value_2",
    "G_key3": "Value_3",
    "g_key1": "Value_4"
}
```

I was expecting same json as an output of the Lookup activity as well but my Lookup activity produces below result:
[image]

It looks like ADF is performing some operation in the backend which treats **G_key1** and **g_key1** as same key and discards all the next instances of the case insensitive key while stores the last key's value in the JSON.

As far as I understand JSON keys are case sensitive, why am I getting this results ?

Any additional suggestions/ approach would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your scenario with the following sample input JSON in lookup activity and ended up with same result as yours.

[image]

[image]

I tried the same with CSV data (different case column names) and got the same kind of results for csv type data as well.

> It looks like ADF is performing some operation in the backend which treats **G_key1** and **g_key1** as same key and discards all the next instances of the case insensitive key while stores the last key's value in the JSON.

**AFAIK**, it's not with ADF. Only lookup is treating the data like that because I am able to see the correct data when I checked the dataset preview. It's the same with other formats of the data and lookup treating the keys like SQL columns(in terms of case) might be the reason for it.

To get the JSON, you can try the below workaround using **ADF Dataflow sink cache**.

Create a dataflow and give your JSON. Go to **Source options -> JSON settings** and select **Single document**. Import the projection of the source.

In sink give the below configurations.

[image]

In pipeline, create a data flow activity and give the above dataflow to it. Make sure the logging is set to None in the data flow activity settings.

You can see I am able to get the JSON without skipping any records in the dataflow activity output.

[image]

You can access this JSON object in the pipeline with below dynamic content and use it as per your requirement.

```
@activity('Data flow1').output.runStatus.output.sink1.value[0]
```

Comment: Thanks for trying out multiple scenarios and suggesting the data flow approach, is this a kind of bug in adf or there is some option which is causing this issue ?